# Size of bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I have to use drawable in my code with icon, because I want to set background in my holder.

```
holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

`itemView` is instance of `View`.

Unfortunately I cannot set size attributes for in xml.

my_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/background"/>
    </item>
    <item android:right="16dp">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Question**

Is it possible to set size of icon in my drawable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) and to this post [Android bitmap image size in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079355/android-bitmap-image-size-in-xml) it is not possible to set the size in xml

Answer (score 0):

In your Drawbles folder, there are subfolders.  Each of those denotes a different size, sm, med, lg, xlg, etc...

Put the same image, at different sizes, with the exact same filename into those folders.  The device will choose the most appropriate size automatically.

A good example would be your launcher icon.  Eclipse will already provide you with like 5 default sizes for just this reason.