# Android Splash Screen: Scale Bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen, screen-density, pixel-density

I'm basically using the following xml's for an Android **Splash Screen**: Empty activity with `windowBackground`:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

`background_splash.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/defaultBackground" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:tileMode="disabled"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This works fine as long the `logo.png` is smaller than the screen size. **If the `logo.png` is bigger than the screen it goes beyond the screen.**

I see 3 workarounds, but all have drawbacks:

1. [Setting `left`/`right` in `<item`, but this requires API 23+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47266146/1349529)
2. Vary `@drawable/logo` for `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi` etc. but I'm using Density Split, which would break it when reusing apk's for other devices (apk sites, "Move to new device"-Apps that transfer apks etc.)
3. Use layout with an `ImageView`, but this has an noticeable delay

**How to do it correctly / without drawbacks?**

Comment: It is not an answer - can you use vector drawables?

Comment: @EugenMartynov Have not triedyet , but I wanted to support API 17+. Since vectors are only supported natively for API 21+ and API 17-20 devices are usually slow/old I'd think that there would be a noticeable delay for showing logo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found no good solution, so I looked at how Google Drive's splashscreen is implemented.

Basically they use a single `splash.png` with 384x384px and put it in `drawable-xhdpi` and used the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list android:opacity="opaque"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/defaultBackground" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

That seems to look good on all devices (that I tested) and solves my issues (specifically 2). Highly recommended!